# Using sapply(,,simplify=TRUE)

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

I have an list of models and want to return an *array* (not a list) of their coefficients.  (For the curious, I am running a single model on data from a bunch of different neurons.  I would like an array that is coefficients X neurons.)  The following works fine if all the models run successfully:

```
Coefs = sapply(ModelList, coef)
```

But if one of the models fails, then coef() returns 'NULL', which is a different length from the other return values, and I end up with a list instead of an array.  :(

My solution is works and is general purpose, but is horribly clumsy:

```
Coefs = sapply(ModelList, coef)
typical = Coefs[[1]]             # (ought to ensure that this is not NULL!)
typical[1:length(typical)] = NA  # Replace all coefficients with NA
Bad = sapply(ModelList, is.null) # Find the bad entries
for (i in which(Bad))            # For each 'NULL',  (UGH!  A LOOP!)
   Coefs[[i]] = typical          #  replace with a proper entry (of NAs) 
Coefs = simplify2array(Coefs)    # Now I can convert it to an array
```

Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still a little clumsy:

```
sapply(ModelList, function(x) ifelse(is.null(coef(x)), NA, coef(x))
```